# postgres: NOT IN array instead of NOT EXISTS expression

Tags: postgresql, performance, redis

my project matches randomly a pair of users. they can exit the game and get matched randomly with other users.

i don't want 2 users can be matched again and again for a while.

i save all my data like user_id, lang, gender etc on a postgres table.

In order not to match them again for a while i was using redis sorted lists and unix time to store the couples of users matched. I decided to use redis because my project store like 1 million of couples per day.

when i have to match an user with another user i get from redis the list of the users matched with him in the last x minutes and i pass them in a 'where user_id not in ()" (they are never more than 200 and in case i limit it to 200) when i run the query to find an available user to match with him.

in this way i can't use the exists or join form that should be faster than IN. Should i then consider to use postgres also to store the couple despite i should write 1 million of them per day (of course i can delete those rows after a while), to run the query using EXISTS or JOIN instead of NOT IN passing a tuple?.

i am wondering about performances.

Comment: Test joining on a `VALUES` table-expression as a subquery in `FROM`. IIRC that was fastest for lots of values. I wrote a post about it a while ago, search my history.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta do some probabilities here...

Say you have Nu = 1 million online users.

The user clicked on "match" Nm = 200 times today.

The user clicks on "match" again. We want to match them with a random user which is not part of the list of 200 previous matches.

Picking a user at random, we have only Nm/Nu probability of picking one which was matched with this user in the last 200 matches. This is only 200/10000000 = 0.002% probability.

In this case, and since the list of past matches is not stored into postgres, it makes a lot more sense to:

- Simply get a match, without bothering to inserting the 200 integers into the SELECT...
- Then check if the matched user is in the list of previous matches
- If so, repeat.

You only have a very small chance of having to run the loop again, but the query is lightened every single time (no more need for postgres to parse 200 ints).

Now, if you had stored your match data into postgres instead of redis... 1M INSERTS a day is 11.5 INSERTS/second, which is negligible... then you could implement this with one query. As long as pg uses a Nested Loop over your random number generator and stops on a LIMIT 1, it'll work just the same.